# How to create object member variable that contains a function pointer

Tags: javascript, function, object, delegates

In Javascript, I have an object that contains a member variable called "dialogHost". It is itself an object that can call different functions. Currently, the way I have it set up is that in most cases, the object's dialogHost value is undefined. In the rare cases where it needs to be defined, I define it to be something like "window.parent" for example. The problem with setting it up this way is that any time I need to use this member variable, I have to check whether it is defined first, like:

```
var myDelegate;

if (typeof (myObject.dialogHost) !== 'undefined') {
    myDelegate = myObject.dialogHost.someFunction;
} else {
    myDelegate = someFunction;
}

myDelegate(...);
```

I have to do this type of check in a few places and it would be nice if the value always existed. Should I simply provide a default value of "window" for dialogHost in this case? I'm not sure if that is a good idea or not. Basically, I want the default value to be such that I can simply call:

```
// This would be equivalent to myDelegate(...) above...
myObject.dialogHost.someFunction(...);
```

Without having to do the above checks every time. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript the very good practice is development with ***"avoiding global variables as much you can"***.

> Should I simply provide a default value of "window" for dialogHost in
>   this case? - **No**, don't rely on global `window` object. Use *closures* and *immediate functions*.

```
var myObject = {
        'dialogHost': function(){
                          // doing some good stuff
                      }
    },
    myDelegate;

myDelegate = (function(obj){
   function someFunction(){    // local function, not accessible from outside
       // doing some good stuff too
   }

   return (typeof obj.dialogHost === 'function')? obj.dialogHost : someFunction;

   }
)(myObject);

// Now you can use myDelegate() function anywhere below 
myDelegate(...);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I meant to say that dialogHost is itself an object as well (not a function pointer). dialogHost contains a function pointer. Typically, dialogHost would basically be the window object. Unfortunately, there are global functions defined throughout the scripts and changing them would be a bigger undertaking.